# Angular: how to programmatically copy a value from one field to another?

Tags: javascript, angular

Another Angular question... I have the following component that I use in a parent (template-driven) form. (FWIW, I am using PrimeFaces UI components.) When the user clicks the "No" radio button, I would like to autopopulate the mailing address/city/state/ZIP fields from the corresponding fields above. This would be easy in plain JavaScript, but I want to do this in the proper Angular fashion. (I suspect my data binding is WAY improper...) Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help!

Screen capture:
[image]

Component code:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { DropdownOptions } from 'src/assets/dropdownOptions';
import { ApplicantInformation } from 'src/app/_models/applicantInformation.model';
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-applicant-information',
  templateUrl: './applicant-information.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./applicant-information.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }] // used to link inputs to the parent form
})
export class ApplicantInformationComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string = '';
  phone = '';
  address = '';
  city = '';
  state = 'AL';
  zipCode = '';
  mailAddrDifferentFromPhysical: string = 'false';
  mailingAddress = '';
  mailingCity = '';
  mailingState = 'AL';
  mailingZIPCode = '';

  options: any = new DropdownOptions;
  sts: string[] = [];

  @Input() ngModel: any = new ApplicantInformation(
    this.name,
    this.phone,
    this.address,
    this.city,
    this.state,
    this.zipCode,
    this.mailAddrDifferentFromPhysical,
    this.mailingAddress,
    this.mailingCity,
    this.mailingState,
    this.mailingZIPCode,
  )

  @Output() nameEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  onFirstColEntered(name: any) {
    this.nameEvent.emit(name);
  }

  handleRadioClick(str: string) {
    this.mailAddrDifferentFromPhysical = str;
  }

  constructor() {
    this.sts = this.options.strAbbrs;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

Template code (partial):

```
      <label for="address">Address</label>
      <input type="text"
        pInputText
        name="address" id="address"
        [ngModel] #address="ngModel"
        required [minlength]="8" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" trim="blur"
        placeholder="Address"
        (change)="onFirstColEntered(address)">

...

      <p class="lg:col-12 md:col-12">
        My mailing address is different than the one above. &nbsp;
        <p-radioButton
          name="mailAddrDifferentFromPhysical" inputId="mailAddrDifferentFromPhysical"
          value="true"
          label="Yes"
          ngModel
          (onClick)="handleRadioClick('true');onFirstColEntered(mailAddrDifferentFromPhysical)"></p-radioButton>
        <p-radioButton
          name="mailAddrDifferentFromPhysical"
          value="false"
          label="No"
          ngModel
          (onClick)="handleRadioClick('false');onFirstColEntered(mailAddrDifferentFromPhysical)"></p-radioButton>
      </p>

...

          <label for="mailingAddress">Mailing Address</label>
          <input type="text"
            pInputText
            name="mailingAddress" id="mailingAddress"
            (ngModel)="address?.value" #mailingAddress="ngModel"
            required [minlength]="8" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" trim="blur"
            placeholder="Mailing Address"
            (change)="onFirstColEntered(mailingAddress)">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set your *mailing* values to the above values when the user sets the radion button value to yes i.e. true.

You can use the method that you're already using *(onClick method)* in the radio button for setting the values.

For example, it should look like this:

```js
 handleRadioClick(str: string) {
    this.mailAddrDifferentFromPhysical = str;
    this.mailingCity = this.city;
    this.mailingAddress = this.address
    //and so on for the rest of the fields
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. It doesn't populate the mailing fields, and when I console.log the results, this.mailingAddress (and the other values) are empty.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my data binding (or lack thereof) WAS the issue. I enclosed the `ngModel` attribute in square brackets on the fields I wanted to copy, then referred to that value in the receiving field, i.e.:

```
<input type="text"
  pInputText
  name="mailingAddress" id="mailingAddress"
  [ngModel]="address?.value" #mailingAddress="ngModel"
  required [minlength]="8" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" trim="blur"
  placeholder="Mailing Address"
  (change)="onFirstColEntered(mailingAddress)">
```